# Flask Jinja Template '<br>'.join

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a list:

```
list = ['var','var','var']
```

In my Jinja template I want to do:

```
{{'<br>'.join(list)}}
```

But the `<br>` actually shows on the page. Is there a way to do this without adding another

```
{% for item in list %}
{{item}}
<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If every element in the list is **safe** (i.e. does not contain markup, or characters that should be escaped before being inserted in the result) then you can mark it as such:

```
{{'<br>'.join(list)|safe}}
```

To be sure, you should escape every item on `list` before feeding it to the template engine, if you want to use it that way. Otherwise, your page may become vulnerable to [HTML Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML_Injection)/[XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) (especially if your list contains user submitted data).

**Update:** as pointed out by @Doobeh, the [`join` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#join) accepts a custom safe separator, so you can use that instead, and the contents of `list` will still be escaped:

```
{{ list|join('<br>'|safe) }}
```

Comment: `{{ list|join('<br>'|safe) }}` seems more Jinjery, and you don't have to care about the contents of list.